# How to save sessions in a Postgres database?

Tags: python, postgresql, session, flask

In one of our new projects, we want to store the session data in to a PostgreSQL database.

I have found several code snippet on the internet to do this, but none were specific for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Flask-Session project](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); it offers a Flask session implementation that can store data in any [SQLAlchemy supported database](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/), including PostgreSQL.

1. Install one of the [supported PostgreSQL client libraries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html); most people use [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).
2. Install [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/); it'll pull in SQLAlchemy when you do. This library integrates SQLAlchemy with Flask.
3. Install Flask-Session and configure it to use the SQLAlchemy session type and a PostgreSQL connection URI; do so by adding the following configuration options to your Flask configuration:

   ```
    SESSION_TYPE = "sqlalchemy"
    # URI to connect to the database. postgresql:// uses psycopg2, see the documentation
    SESSION_SQLALCHEMY = "postgresql://<user>:<password>@hostname:port/database"
    # What table in the database to use, default is "sessions"
    SESSION_SQLALCHEMY_TABLE = "sessions"
   ```
4. Use the Flask-Session extension in your Flask app; the following code assumes you have a `app` variable that is the `Flask()` object, already configured with the above configuration:

   ```py
   from flask_session import Session

   # app has been set and configured
   Session(app)

   # alternatively, create a `Session()` object without passing in app
   # and then when ready, use `.init_app(app)`:
   # sess = Session()
   # sess.init_app(app)
   ```

To emphasise: because Flask-Session uses SQLAlchemy, it works with *all database engines supported by SQLAlchemy*, not just PostgreSQL. So the above would work for SQLite, MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Firebird, Sybase, and any number of other databases with third-party SQLAlchemy dialect packages available.

Comment: Thank for the prompt and clear answer. Actually, I was working with Apache Superset application which is built on apache Flask. With your answer, I could achieve my requirement. Thanks once more.

Comment: @BinuVPillai: Apache Superset builds on top of Flask; so it's not "Apache Flask", just "Flask". Apache Superset is really just a Flask application with specific configuration and extensions already set up for you, changing how it handles sessions doesn't differ from other Flask applications.